# How do I get multiple cursors throughout OSX?

Tags: macos, finder, cursor

I enjoy using the Sublime Text 3 editor—especially the multiple cursors feature.

I constantly find myself in need of the multiple cursor functionality in other OS X apps like Finder or Outlook. Does anyone know if this is possible and how to go about doing this?

Comment: This isn't something that could be added in by an end-user, it would have to be added by the developer of each program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple cursors isn't a feature supported by Mac OS X by default. Some apps have it and if you want it in the rest of the system you will need too find an third part plugin.

I think it would be hard to make that work even with a plugin. But if you haven't already I would recommend giving Google a try in finding one.

Here is a link to an similar discussion on Super User: [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/649325/two-mice-two-pointers-one-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it theoretically could be hacked into the OS, most third party apps wouldn't work. You might have to edit things you need in ST3 or [vim](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) and have to see if the other apps like Outlook can import the files.

Alternatively, you might look for terminal versions of tools like mail tool like [alpine](http://patches.freeiz.com/alpine/) or [emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761706/in-emacs-edit-multiple-lines-at-once) such that rely on the keyboard control far more than a pointer/mouse/trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually an app that does this:  [Multiscreen Multimouse](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multiscreen-multimouse-enable/id1135196075?l=en&mt=12)

I find it very useful for having multiple screens and having less "travel time" between them.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give link-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  Links can change over time and then we'll lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -

Comment: The linked app no longer appears to be available in the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 0):

One of the original answers by Allan no longer seems to be available on the AppStore. A quick google for the blog for the same app does't seem to provide a download link either.

I therefore wrote my own version called Dynamouse:

https://github.com/projectstorm/dynamouse

(you can find the links to the .dmg under the releases page).

While not exactly multiple cursors, it does allow you to assign a pointer-device to a monitor, and will intelligently remember the position as you move each pointer device.

While every OS doesn't support this natively (such as the commenters pointed out):

I personally needed this type of capability because I have a music studio with different monitors connected to the same computer, but in different locations. Having a mouse connected to each screen requires me to otherwise drag the mouse device over to each screen, which is further a problem when you cant even see the other screen. I hope MacOS eventually provides support for 'actual' multiple cursors, since they have at least finally added support for multiple devices being connected at the same time.